# How to generate all possible association rule using frequent itemset?

Tags: python, data-mining, apriori, association-rule-mining

I have a dictionary with key as frequent itemsets and value as support of that itemset. Now, I want to generate all possible association rule (X --> Y). How can I do this? Is there any inbuilt python function to do this?

Using the generated association rule, I want to calculate strong association rule (rules that have confidence greater than minimum confidence). I can do this but how to generate all association rule?